# $\prod_\rho (1-\frac{s}{\rho})$=$\prod_{\Im(\rho)>0 }(1-\frac{s}{\rho})(1-\frac{s}{1-{\rho}})$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

I am reading H.M. Edwards Riemann zeta function and in page 42 section 2.5 he writes these 2 products equal. I am not able to understand.

$\prod_\rho (1-\frac{s}{\rho})$=$\prod_{\Im(\rho)>0 }(1-\frac{s}{\rho})(1-\frac{s}{1-{\rho}})$
where $\rho $ is the non trivial zero of the Riemann Zeta function...

Comment: If $\rho$ is a zero in the upper half-plane, then $1-\rho$ is a zero in the lower half-plane, and vice versa. The right hand side just groups these pairs of zeros together.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Can you please elaborate. I cannot get you. Sorry

Comment: It's the same as $$\prod_{n \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}} \biggl(1 - \frac{z}{n^3}\biggr) = \prod_{k = 1}^{\infty} \biggl(1 - \frac{z}{k^3}\biggr)\biggl(1 - \frac{z}{(-k)^3}\biggr)\,,$$ only that instead of gouping $k$ and $-k$ you group $\rho$ and $1-\rho$, and that since $\sum \frac{1}{\lvert \rho\rvert} = +\infty$ you need to take the product on the left hand side in a specific order.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer But can you please post it as an answer.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Can i write $\prod_\rho (1-\frac{s}{\rho})= \prod_{\Im(\rho)>0 }(1-\frac{s}{\rho})(1-\frac{s}{1-\bar{\rho}})$

Comment: No. $1 - \overline{\rho} = \rho$ if $\rho$ lies on the critical line (so we expect that to be the case for all $\rho$), in any case $1 - \overline{\rho}$ lies in the upper half-plane if $\rho$ does, so that product omits all zeros in the lower half plane, and uses those in the upper twice. You can write $\prod_{\Im(\rho) > 0} (1 - s/\rho)(1 - s/\overline{\rho})$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer One last question Can i write $ \prod_\rho (1-\frac{s}{\rho}) = \prod_{\Im(\rho)>0 , \Re(\rho)<1/2}(1-\frac{s}{\rho})(1-\frac{s}{1-{\rho}})$